# webview ip address

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview

I have set up a webview on an iOS7 app.
I can successfully load a webpage as long as it is formatted correctly (including the http://)
ultimately I am hoping to connect to an ip address - similar to the web interface on a router for instance, however the webview doesn't seem to like the format.
Is there a way I can reformat the address in such a way that it will be processed by the webview?

Thanks,

Comment: What format are you suing? The format is (example address): `http://192.168.1.1:8080/page.html`

Comment: NSURL classs requires URLs employed are described in RFCs 1808, 1738, and 2732, So make sure it has http:// or https://

Comment: Yes you had to add the port as well, mine is http://XXX:XXX:XX:XX:80/login

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your original post mention, using `http://127.0.0.1`, adding the http:// to the beginning is valid and it does work. I just tested it.

Comment: Thanks Paul,I have tried that, and it just seems to load a blank view.

Comment: Do you mean `http://127.0.0.1` gave you a blank view? I was just using that as an example. I am running a local web server so my UIWebView does actually resolve that specific IP-based URL to a site on my machine, so I know it does work. 

Do you have a specific IP-based URL that you are trying to reach? You can try `http://66.6.44.4` which will pull up a tumblr error page...

Comment: I meant that I get a blank screen when attempting to dial into my routers IP including the http:// (I can do it using safari without a problem). The tumblr error page does display correctly though. I am wondering now if it is related to the fact that my router displays a password prompt as a popup. I will ultimately be connecting to the IP of some industrial equipment which I will test tomorrow. Thanks,

Comment: Hey @CraigSanderson i'm facing same issue. m including 'http://' but still its showing blank page.

Comment: Hi - I have to admit I abandoned that project as I could never get it to play ball! I would be interested to know if you get yours working - especially as Xcode has changed quite a bit since I was having the issue! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned befor, you have to use http://. But you'll get a blank view because in iOS http requests are by default "deactivated".
To "activate" the http:// request, you have to go into your info-plist and add
"App Transport Security Settings" and inside of the setting you add "Allows Arbitrary Loads" and change the value from NO to YES.

[image]